# Momentjs date '06/05/2021' with format 'M/D/YY' considered as Fri Jun 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300.... Why and how handle that?

Tags: momentjs

Momentjs date '06/05/2021' with format 'M/D/YY' considered as 'Fri Jun 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300...'. Is it more logical that it have to be 2021. Is it a bug or no? Why does it convert dates this way and how handle that?

Comment: Could you post what code you use to get this wrong output? Got nothing to go by which makes this unanswerable.

Comment: I can't reproduce this: http://jsfiddle.net/xgh2wayd/

Comment: just go to console of momentjs.com and insert moment('06/05/2021', 'M/D/YY'). It consired it as Fri Jun 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300... but why? is it more logical to be 2021 year not 2020

Comment: ok I just edited the question, as far as the description was not correct

Comment: Try this `moment('06/05/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'). format('M/D/YY)`, this return `6/5/21`, if you want double digits for days and month use this `moment('06/05/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'). format('MM/DD/YY)`

Comment: I mostly interested in why is that this way? Because for some reason it consider correctly day and month, but not year. Is there any logic behind this

Comment: the first parameter inside the brackets of `moment()` is the date, if the this first patameter is not a standard format of date or a Date object you must explain the string format in the second parameter, the method `.format('...')` is the format of date that you want a date in string format.
For learn how work the string for formatter there is the documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: The second parameter of [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) is the format that you pass to moment to let him parse strings that are not in ISO 8601. I think that, since you are using `YY` (two digit year), the first 2 digit after `/` are considered as the year (`20` => `2020`). Anyway, it's not a momentjs bug, you should use `MM/DD/YYYY` instead of `M/D/YY`